# How does gdal.ReprojectImage() work?

Tags: python, gdal, georeferencing, modis, hdf

I'm using gdal.ReprojectImage() to reproject mod021km bands to geotif data. it takes one of the modis multiband subdatasets (e.g. EV_500_Aggr1km_RefSB with 5 bands) and saves it as a tif file with one band as a result (i did test it and get result). as far as i need to reproject every band, i tried to save each band of subdataset ('tmp_band.hdf') at first, read it by gdal.Open() and feed it to the gdal.ReprojectImage but i got these errors:

> RuntimeError: The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed for tmp_band.hdf. There is no affine transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check.

the code i used to save bands and feed them to gdal.ReprojectImage is:

```
def _reprojectOne(self, l, quiet=False):
    """Reproject a single subset of MODIS product
    l = complete name of input dataset
    """
    l_src_ds = gdal.Open(l)
    number_of_bands = l_src_ds.RasterCount
    meta = l_src_ds.GetMetadata()
    band = l_src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    bands = l_src_ds.ReadAsArray()
    if '_FillValue' in list(meta.keys()):
        fill_value = meta['_FillValue']
    elif band.GetNoDataValue():
        fill_value = band.GetNoDataValue()
    else:
        fill_value = None
    datatype = band.DataType
    try:
        l_name = l.split(':')[-1]
        out_name = "{pref}_{lay}".format(pref=self.output_pref,
                                             lay=l_name)
    except:
        out_name = "{pref}".format(pref=self.output_pref)
    if self.vrt:
        out_name = "{pref}".format(pref=self.output_pref)

    for i in range(number_of_bands):
        tmp_ds = l_src_ds.GetDriver().Create('tmp_band.hdf',
                                    l_src_ds.RasterXSize,
                                    l_src_ds.RasterYSize,
                                    1, datatype)
        m = tmp_ds.GetRasterBand(i+1)
        m.WriteArray(bands[i,:,:])
        tmp_ds.SetGeoTransform(l_src_ds.GetGeoTransform())
        tmp_ds.SetProjection(l_src_ds.GetProjection())

        m.FlushCache()
        tmp_ds = None

        try:
            tmp_src_ds = gdal.Open('tmp_band.hdf')
            dst_ds = self.driver.Create(out_name+'_B{b}.tif'.format(b=i+1),
                                        self.dst_xsize,
                                        self.dst_ysize,
                                        1, datatype)
        except:
            raise Exception('Not possible to create dataset %s' % out_name)
        dst_ds.SetProjection(self.dst_wkt)
        dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(self.dst_gt)
        if fill_value:
            dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(float(fill_value))
            dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).Fill(float(fill_value))
        cbk = self._progressCallback
        # value for last parameter of above self._progressCallback
        cbk_user_data = None
        try:
            gdal.ReprojectImage(tmp_src_ds, dst_ds, tmp_src_ds.GetProjection(),
                                self.dst_wkt, self.resampling, 0,
                                self.error_threshold, cbk, cbk_user_data)
            if not quiet:
                print("Layer {name} reprojected".format(name=l))
        except:
            raise Exception('Not possible to reproject dataset '
                            '{name}'.format(name=l))
        dst_ds.SetMetadata(meta)
        dst_ds = None
        l_src_ds = None
```

where is the problem? how can i feed the specific band to the gdal.ReprojectImage?
should i save more information in 'tmp_band'(information from subdataset metadata)?

Note: the original code is a script named [convertmodis_gdal.py](https://github.com/lucadelu/pyModis/blob/master/pymodis/convertmodis_gdal.py) that is used by [modis_convert.py](https://github.com/lucadelu/pyModis/blob/master/scripts/modis_convert.py)

Comment: Isn't it telling you exactly how to fix the error? `Specify transformation option SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check`